# Error when call self.setValue(:forKey:)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a following VC:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var platforms = [Platform]()

    viewDidLoad() {
        let newPlatforms = [Platform(0), Platform(1)]
        self.setValue(newPlatforms, forKey: "platforms")
    }
}
```

but when run i get that crash error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   **platforms**

but its ok when i use, for example, string variable

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var string = ""

    viewDidLoad() {
        let newString = "Hello world"
        self.setValue(newString, forKey: "string")
    }
}
```

I really need this key-value coding mechanism. The example specially simplified.

Comment: Why are you using `setValue(_:forKey:)`?

Comment: According to this article, the observed value (`platforms`) needs to inherit from NSObject, and since a Swift array is not even a class, it's an struct, it might not be able to be observed. https://medium.com/proto-venture-technology/the-state-of-kvo-in-swift-aa5cb1e05cba#.tse34ddpo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`platforms` is an array(!), to set the array use this simple syntax

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var platforms = [Platform]()

    viewDidLoad() {
        let newPlatforms = [Platform(0), Platform(1)]
        platforms = newPlatforms
    }
}
```

`self` is not needed.

---

Or in the second example assign a `String`

```
string = newString
```

Basically don't use `valueForKey:` / `setValue:forKey:` unless you **really** need the KVC (key-value-coding) functionality.

Comment: i really need to use KVC. Example is specially simplified for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

self is currently referring to ViewController. You should use dictionary for storing key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var optionDictionary : NSMutableDictionary!
optionDictionary.setValue(newPlatforms, forKey: "platforms") //or setObject if value is not work.
```

Try this. hope this will work :)